# What software should I use to manage my web applications development process?

Tags: software-development, project-management, version-control

I know Git as a version control that a team of developers can work on codes. But I am interested to know is there any other more comprehensive software that has another extra options to define tasks for each developer and he/she can see his/her daily tasks and do it and the software will show the completed tasks and the whole project's progress, etc?

I mean some combination of project management and version control software?

Answer (score 1):

With [GitHub](https://github.com/) you can create kanban boards besides version control. So you can define columns like Todo, In progress, Done... In the columns you can store tickets which can be assigned to developers. The ideal thing here is the seamless integration of code and kanban boards.

You can also define milestones, work with labels, create a wikis... 
In my daily developer and project management life I do not really miss anything.

Here you find information about GitHub Boards: https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-project-boards

Otherwise you could also use [Trello](https://trello.com/) as a Kanban Board. I also do that in a few projects. There is an add on in Trello that gives tickets an ID. We include this ID in the commit messages. Works great too. I even like the Trello Kanban boards more than the GitHub ones, with the disadvantage that the code is not seamlessly integrated.